# Does a Magento Module Validator Exists?

Tags: magento

I'm writing a module and for the life of me I can't get it to work. I've made several modules in the past so I'm guessing I have some stupid mistake somewhere.  Does anyone know if there's a Magento module validator out there to point out problems with a modules structure and format?

Comment: Are you having a problem with submitting to Magento Connect?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The closest thing is the [configuration lint](http://alanstorm.com/magento_config_lint) system I built a while back.  While far from a full fledged validator, it checks for common configuration errors and allows you to write you own test.

The first unofficial steps of manual validation involve checking the "Disable Module Output" section of the magento admin to see if your module is loading. If it doesn't show up in there, that means there's a problem with your

```
etc/module/*.xml
```

file.  (maybe code pool?)

Comment: thanks for the input there.  The strange thing was the module was enable in the panel you referred too. Eventually I took a working module, copied it and then replaced its contents with what I had written in the other module and viola! it worked.  I never did find the problem, but it must have been so minuscule it escaped hours of looking over the code.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't any validators that I'm aware of.  Sometimes the best thing to do is to start a new module and slowly re-build it.  Keep adding very small pieces of functionality or configuration at a time.  You'll eventually find out what doesn't work.

With Magento, there are so many places it can go wrong, even down to improper capitalization of words in your config.xml file.  I can't tell you how many times I've made dumb mistakes that I spent hours trying to figure out, and it was a misspelling or something silly.

Good luck.  I hope you can figure it out soon!